# Nesting Dynamic Objects

Tags: javascript, object

I have been having issues with this and I am just not getting the right technique implemented. It is kinda specific so I have had trouble tracking down an explanation online so far. Ok here it is:

I am looping through a large json object and creating a second object that has in it objects containing the information which I want to use later.

```
items = {};
$(data).each(function () {
    i = 0;
    $(list).each(function () {
        if (list[i]["name"] === category) {
            add = false;
        }
        i++;
    });
    if (add === true) {
        list.push({name: category,info: 0, items: items});
    }
```

My issue is this when I then try to add an item to items in a particular category, it add it to all categories, so:

```
list[0]["items"]["msg"] = "Test";
```

Adds test to all my category objects, and not simply to the first one. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Please post your whole script, not only this fragment. What is `i` needed for?

Comment: Would you mind posting part of the json struct? It is hard to follow because the content of the list var is not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Adds test to all my category objects, and not simply to the first one. Can anyone tell me why?

It adds the `msg` property to the *one, single* `items` object which is references from all the objects in the list. If you want distinctive objects, use

```
    list.push({name: category,info: 0, items: {}});
```

instead.